# arm-elf-g++: Command not found

Tags: c++, linux

I try to compile `live555` library for eCos system. I don't pretty sure how to do this, so i try option build this under arm compiler. so as tutorial online. I type :

```
./genMakefiles armlinux
```

after that, i type : `make` and meet this error:

```
arm-elf-g++: Command not found
```

I think that `arm-elf-g++` compiler that my machine doesn't install yet. I google, but no result how to install. (i'm currently using Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit). please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

`sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`

Here are a couple of links for installing an ARM toolchain on Ubuntu:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/65630/installing-gnu-arm-toolchain
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/levana-technologies/MiGqkDn3ARQ

Comment: i have installed gcc-arm-linux toolchain. but i still meet above error :( maybe this toolchain does not contain arm-elf-g++ ?